# PythonValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, torchvision, train-test-split

I am getting the following error when trying to split data into train and test.
[image]
[image]

I tried to solve this error but I could not. Please give the solution how to solve this error. Thank you in advance

Comment: "I tried to solve this error but I could not." Specifically what did you try doing, and what happened when you tried that? What do you think the error means, and what do you think is causing it? Did you try to look at the data that you have? Do you understand why that would cause the problem described? If so, what prevents you from fixing the data?

Answer (score 1):

You have not enough sample of `age` column. Try:

```
>>> WikiCrop_df[['age', 'gender']].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x == 1]

age  gender
20   1.0       1
     0.0       1
dtype: int64
```

You will have probably some row where (age, gender) have only one record so you can't stratify your dataframe:

```
>>> train_test_split(WikiCrop_df, test_size=0.2, stratify=WikiCrop_df[['age', 'gender']])
...
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. 
            The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```